# What is a word that means "a span of six months"?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, measuring-units

Is there a word that means "a span of six months"? That is, I want to connote a stretch of time that lasts half a year, not an event that happens every six months.

Comment: Could you give the sentence you intend to use this in?

Comment: That sounds like about a dozen fortnights. :^) I have to ask, though, what's wrong with, say, a _six-month labor dispute_, or a _half-year labor dispute_?

Comment: Side note: In German we have the adjectives "halbjährig" for something lasting half a year and "halbjährlich" for something happening every half year. Its formed regularly, so "viertel-" for "quarter" can be used or the prefix can be omitted entirely for the full year. It also works with every other timespan (month, week, day, ...), always with "-lich" meaning recurrance and "-ig" meaning passed time. I'm really missing something like this in English.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Depending on context, *-ly* can serve as the recurring form (daily, monthly, 6-monthly, etc).

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, that's why it is an issue. Context is needed, the information is not encoded in the word itself.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek My apologies. The *-ly* forms are pretty standard. It’s the base form that’s more context-dependent. Eg: a 2-month checkup probably doesn’t last 2 months, but a 2-monthly checkup is definitely a periodic checkup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[***half year***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20year)
noun

1: one half of a year (as January to June or July to December)
2: one of two academic terms : semester

— ***half–yearly*** adverb or adjective
Origin of *half year*: ME

See also:
'[Half-year convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-year_convention)' is a principle of United States taxation law.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it fixed my issue with this: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105869/38613. I never knew this existed. I also accepted the answer biannually there too. I think half year makes sense and half-yearly (I guess it needs an hyphen) does it.

Answer (score 2):

The SAS (originally *Statistical Analysis System*) coins **semiyear**

( http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/saspdf/ets/chap3.pdf ), but this is hardly common usage.

Surely fmark takes pains to indicate that the adjective *biannual* (or, less ambiguous, semiannual) is *not* what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use *within*.

Examples:

1. You should receive a reply within seven days.
2. Two elections were held within the space of a year.

Reference: *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*

Comment: All your answer does is add another word to the phrase that OP is wishing to shorten.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "six-month event".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word "a semester", I don't know if it goes well with what you are writting but for me that's a period of 6 months