# What's the Best English word for 6 months in this group: daily, weekly, quarterly, 6 months, yearly?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, recurring-events

While writing programs, I need to create a drop down for setting periods, like daily, weekly, monthly, etc. Using one year as a time frame. This question is driven by lack of a better word. I've had some trouble coming up with a one word adjective for 6 months. I do have the following:

```
1 day - Daily,
1 week - Weekly,
1 month - Monthly,
3 months - Quarterly,
6 months - ?
1 year - Yearly or Annually
```

Comment: Just being positioned between "Quarterly" and "Yearly" should mitigate the ambiguity. So either one would be understood. (It won't stop some from making a mental note that it might be the wrong word, but they will still know your intent.) I would go with semiannually, myself. Unfortunately, this question has been marked as a duplicate for which no authoritative reference was provided. So you'll have to be trusting, I guess.

Comment: The question started off as more-or-less clear, then veered off somewhere strange ("*bi-annually* is not one word"), and the update is just a wall of text with no question in sight. Anyway, we have several questions dealing with the ambiguity of *bi-* already. All of them boiling down to "1) yes, it can be ambiguous — big deal, so can be most words —, and 2) no, there is no convenient one-word replacement — again, big deal, neither is there for most things". Nothing wrong with clearly stating "every six months" or "twice a year".

Comment: Steward, I added an answer (to suggest considering *twice-yearly* and *half-yearly*) at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105871/11433 which you can vote up if you feel like.

Comment: @RegDwighт, in the  “more-or-less clear” part, Steward asks, “Could there be a better word for it?” which isn't a duplicate of linked question.  I added an answer at the other question.  But please reopen this question and transfer my answer from the other question to this one.

Comment: Thanks jwpat7, the fact is I'd vote up your answer. One word appearing in two different questions don't make it duplicates. While one question could be about what does bi- stand for, my question is what better one word is there for 6 months like daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly. My guess it there might be one that I don't know of. The link for duplicate don't address my issue, an answer would help. At the moment, I'd go with the one answer I have here. biannually. But there is half-yearly, bi-yearly won't be bad.

Comment: Do we all agree at this point that the word bi- has an ambiguous meaning? It seems to leave me more confused. I'd have to take it for lack of a better alternative. Just one more areas that English falls short of vocabularies.

Comment: @RegDwighт, can I at least confirm is bi- is the same with semi-? Since the question is closed to answer? Semi is half, right? Thanks!

Comment: According to the OED: The definition of biannual is "A) adj. Used as = Half-yearly. B) = BIENNAL,n." So, biannual can be used as an adjective that means every six months, but also as a noun that means every two years. The illustrative quote in the second case is "Plant out..annuals and bi-annuals", which shows how restricted this usage may be. The OED also mentions the adverb *biannually* as derivative; so, the answer to the original question is *biannually*, but to avoid confusion maybe you should use half-yearly.

Comment: @Frog, now you confuse me again. I appreciate all the help here. Now, Since the question has been marked as duplicate, ***Do I have to delete this question to avoid down votes*** or leave it in case others might need it -- and suffer the consequences of a down vote?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/a/81613/14666

Comment: @Frog, your link for possible duplicate makes more sense than the initial one from RegDwight. Now you can completely close the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Biannually
```

Should do the trick, and fits with your running theme of -ly suffixes. It is spelt as one word.

Comment: Thanks, just concerned about this: http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/bi-vs-semi-weeklymonthlyannually/ and http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/difficulties/bisemi.html It says: Bi- comes from the Latin meaning two. When used with a temporal word, bi- means "every two" or "every other." Does that affect the meaning?

Comment: Every two years is *biennially*.

Comment: I was actually looking for every 6 months. Thanks for the response Andrew. @mattacular, I'm thinking towards the same line if I don't get a better suggestion.

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen I was pointing out that *biannually* is fine because the other word (for every two years) is *biennial*. I wasn't suggesting *biennial* for your requirement.

Comment: Okay, I get. That should mean two years then, not half of it. I wish I had a word like that for it. It's such an important time division to not have a word (latin, aramaic or something)!

Comment: I appreciate all the help here. Now, Since the question has been marked as duplicate, ***Do I have to delete this question to avoid down votes*** or leave it in case others might need it -- and suffer the consequences of a down vote?

Comment: A more clearer word would be **Semi-annually*