# Why can't we use 'halfly' to mean 'once every six months?'

Tags: word-usage, recurring-events

I've read other since-closed questions revolving more around taxonomy and best practice as it relates to this recurring problem.

But nothing on this one particular case seems to be in the archives, so I wanted to raise the question.

As in these instances:

- [What is the collective term for "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Yearly"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326819/what-is-the-collective-term-for-daily-weekly-monthly-and-yearly?rq=1)
- [What's the Best English word for 6 months in this group: daily, weekly, quarterly, 6 months, yearly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105869/whats-the-best-english-word-for-6-months-in-this-group-daily-weekly-quarterl)

The origin of my curiosity is in this list of recurrence types (daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly...).

I work with companies that measure time by the day, week, month and quarter... and also by half a year.

My question then, why can't we just use "halfly" here?

It's not like it's not a word already- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halfly) has it.

Comment: See “Is "halfly" a word? “https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106570/is-halfly-a-word#:~:text=on%20this%20post.-,halfly,means%20full.

Comment: Also note that "quarterly" is related to a "quarter" which is commonly used to denote a quarter of a year, yet we don't have the same for "half". The other words you mention are adjectives or adverbs based on nouns that really only denote those specific times.

Comment: You can use it if you want; do you want other people to understand it? Will they work it out from the context? How quickly do you need them to understand it?

Answer (score 3):

I do recommend to use [semiannually](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiannually) to refer to a period of six month.

[Halfly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halfly) is  a rare word, and as Merrian Webster suggests, it doesn’t refer to a period of time.

Comment: And combining *annually* plus *semiannually* equals [*sesquiannually*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesqui-) for every year-and-a-half or 18 months, not to mention [*quasquiannually*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quasquicentennial) for every year-and-a-quarter or 15 months. :)

Comment: Is this really better than half-yearly, which is more immediately understandable (IMO)?

Comment: Same for biannual.